# Get a list of Clusters formed from Dendrogram in Python

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a list of words on which I performed TF-IDF Algorithm to get the list of top 100 words. After which I am supposed to perform clustering. For now I am able to do both of the tasks (I am sharing relevant part of the code and input file, screenshot of output).

My Query is that I wanted the **list of the clusters** that are formed in  the output Dendrogram, How can I do that? The Dendrogram function returns a Tuple `ax` which has some co ordinates and list of the nodes. How can I manipulate them to get the complete list of Clusters.

The following is extract from the input file.

```
"recommended stories dylan scott stat advertisement kate sheridan dylan scott dylan scott",
"email touting former representative mike fergusons genuine connection",
"email touting former representative mike ferguson \u2019",
"facebook donald trump fda hhs privacy policy",
"president trump appoints dr scott gottlieb",
"trade groups including novartis ag",
"bush alumni coalition supporting trump",
"online presidential transition analysis center",
"tennessee republican representative marsha blackburn",
"nonprofit global health care company",
"paula stannard ,\u201d said ladd wiley",
"bremberg returned calls seeking comment",
"0 \u2026. 0 \u2026 1c",
"2016 w ashington \u2014 let",
"take place ,\u201d said dr",
"\u201c selling baby parts .\u201d",
"health care companies whose boards",
"transition ,\u201d said lisa tofil",
```

The following is the code that I am using

```
punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'\<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
n_a =fin_a= ""
for file in os.listdir():
    if (file.endswith(".kwp")):
        with open(file) as f:
            #print(f.read())
            a = f.read()
            a = re.sub(r"\\[a-z0-9A-Z]+","",a)
            a = re.sub(r"\"","",a)
            a = re.sub(r"\,","",a)
            #a = re.sub("\\","",a)
            #print(a)
            for ch in a:
                if (ch not in punctuations):
                    n_a = n_a + ch
            n_a = n_a.lower()
            #print(n_a)
            #new_f = open("n")

        fin_a = fin_a + n_a 

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=1,stop_words='english',use_idf=True)
tfd_mat = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform([n_a])
dense = tfd_mat.todense()
#print(len(dense[0].tolist()[0]))
ep = dense[0].tolist()[0]
phrase_scores = [pair for pair in zip(range(0, len(ep)), ep) if pair[1] > 0]
#print(phrase_scores)
#print(len(phrase_scores))
phrase_scores=sorted(phrase_scores, key=lambda t: t[1] * -1)[:100]
#rint(tfd_mat)
fin_term = []
terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
with open("/home/laitkor/Desktop/New_Paul/kwp_top100.txt","w") as fl:
    for t in range(0,100):
        #print(t)
        key,valu = phrase_scores[t]
        #print(key)
        #print(valu)
        fl.write(terms[key]+'\n')
        fin_term.append(terms[key])
#print(fin_term)    
#print(phrase_scores[1:100])
dist = 1 - cosine_similarity(phrase_scores[1:100])
#print(dist)
linkage_matrix = ward(dist)
#print(linkage_matrix)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 30)) # set size
ax = dendrogram(linkage_matrix, orientation="right", labels=fin_term);
#print(ax)
#print(leaves)
plt.tick_params(\
    axis= 'x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off')

plt.tight_layout() #show plot with tight layout

#uncomment below to save figure
plt.savefig('kw[enter image description here][1]p.png', dpi=200)
```

The below link contains the output of the Dendrogram formed

https://www.screencast.com/t/2MEc3ohBe

Answer (score 7):

You need to know beforehand how many clusters you want; then you can use:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster
fl = fcluster(cl,numclust,criterion='maxclust')
```

where `cl` is the output of your linkage method and `numclust` is the number of clusters you want to get.

Comment: helps me a lot, and the criterion='maxclust' parameter is a must !